# Liquibase - Empty row error when querying Informix DB user

Tags: liquibase, informix

I'm randomly getting the following error when I sync an Informix DB with Liquibase:

```
2020-03-16 14:48:26 INFO  (Log4jLogger.java:36) - Error getting connection schema
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Expected single row from select username from sysmaster:informix.syssessions where sid = dbinfo('sessionid') but got 0
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:146) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:157) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:152) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.database.core.InformixDatabase.getConnectionSchemaName(InformixDatabase.java:237) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getDefaultSchemaName(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:305) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogParameters.<init>(ChangeLogParameters.java:54) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.<init>(Liquibase.java:104) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Empty result set, expected one row
    at liquibase.util.JdbcUtils.requiredSingleResult(JdbcUtils.java:141) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:144) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    ... 18 more

2020-03-16 14:48:26 INFO  (Log4jLogger.java:36) - Error getting connection schema
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Expected single row from select username from sysmaster:informix.syssessions where sid = dbinfo('sessionid') but got 0
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:146) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:157) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:152) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.database.core.InformixDatabase.getConnectionSchemaName(InformixDatabase.java:237) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.getDefaultSchemaName(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:305) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogParameters.<init>(ChangeLogParameters.java:55) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.<init>(Liquibase.java:104) [liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Empty result set, expected one row
    at liquibase.util.JdbcUtils.requiredSingleResult(JdbcUtils.java:141) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:144) ~[liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
```

If I run the select producing the error, I always get the corresponding single row with the DB user. As said, the error comes up randomly, usually during the first attempts to sync the DB. But after several attempts, it works.

Any ideas about why this happens?

I'm using Liquibase 3.5.5 and Informix 12.10.FC9W1.

Comment: The error appears to be from: `select username from sysmaster:informix.syssessions where sid = dbinfo('sessionid')`.  That should return information in one row, but it is returning zero rows instead.  That's a long-winded way of writing `SELECT USER FROM informix.systables WHERE tabid = 1` or any of the equivalent ways of selecting a single row from somewhere.  USER is a niladic (zero-argument) function (which therefore takes no parentheses — adding parentheses yields a -674 error) returning the name of the session.  These days, using `SELECT USER FROM sysmaster:informix.sysdual` also works.

Comment: As to why it is not returning a row — that is unclear.  It ought not to be possible; the current session should be recorded in the `syssessions` SMI table in the `sysmaster` database.  It may be a lot to ask, but does the problem persist if you restart the Informix instance?  If you have support, consider contacting IBM or HCL Technical Support, as appropriate.  All the ways I can think of the problem occurring are devious and indicative of problems elsewhere too.  Are you sure your server is healthy (a serious bout of running `oncheck` commands might be in order)?

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for your suggestions. I'll keep running more tests with the alternative select statements. The server is healthy as far as I know, but will re-check as well.